# parsing HTML with domDocument and DOMXPath

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument, domxpath

I am getting this code into a **$html** variable:

```
...
...
<table id="tbvalue" class="table_main">
<tr align="center">
<td>
    <div style='background-color:#534522;' ><img src="operation.bmp" border="0" alt="image" width="250" height="60" /></div>
    <br />
</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
    <td class="other">
        more text
    </td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
    <td>
    <input name="name" type="text" id="label" tabindex="1"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <span id="lblErrCap" class="errfont"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
... 
...
```

note: I need that first occurrence of **`<img>`** that's inside of **`table id="tbvalue"`**
I was trying to do this:

```
$dom = new domDocument;

/*** load the html into the object ***/
@$dom->loadHTML($html); // the @ is to silence errors and misconfigures of HTML

/*** discard white space ***/
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$spans = $xpath->query('//img');
echo $spans->item(0)->getAttribute("src");
```

But this query is ignorant of the table **`table id="tbvalue"`** and would simply take the first **`<img>`**.

What is the approach to get the first **`img`** inside **`table id="tbvalue"`** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
<?php
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$spans = $xpath->query('//table[@id="tbvalue"]//img[1]');
echo $spans->item(0)->getAttribute("src");
```

`//` operator means to select nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are

More useful information you can find [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).